# Active directory group scope - Domain local or Global?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, subdomain, security-groups

CONTOSO has offices in the UK and in the US. each country has its own domain, but the domains trust each other.

I have created a group in the AD in UK but if the group is set to `global` I cannot add US users to the group.

As soon as I change the group scope to `domain local` I can allow US users into the UK group.

**QUESTION:**

why is it so?

Do I have to change the group to `domain local` in order to change the location to `CONTOSO.COM` instead of `contoso.co.uk` and be able to search in the US domain, and add US users to this group?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as intended, the [documentation says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups#group-scope):

### Possible members

## Global Group

> - Accounts from the same domain
> - Other Global groups from the same domain

## Domain Local Group

> - Accounts from any domain or any trusted domain
> - Global groups from any domain or any trusted domain
> - Universal groups from any domain in the same forest
> - Other Domain Local groups from the same domain
> - Accounts, Global groups, and Universal groups from other forests and from external domains